# CalendarView Causes App to Crash

Tags: android, android-intent, android-widget, calendarview

Essentially I have an issue with my calendarView widget. In the app whenever it goes from my Main class to the EditProgress class it either freezes or crashes. I tested it, and whenever the calendarView widget is in the EditProgress class the app runs very slowly, and whenever I attempt to use the widget in my .java class it simply crashes. It had complained before saying that it required API level 11, so I tried to fix this by using suppress warnings, but it still crashes or runs slowly. Thank you for any help. Below is my .java class:

```
package com.dwolford.workoutroutine;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CalendarView;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class EditProgress extends Activity {

Button submit;
Button back;
Spinner exercise;
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter;
EditText reps;
CalendarView calendar;
Context context = this;

@TargetApi(11)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_progress);


    exercise = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.Exercises, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    exercise.setAdapter(adapter);
    exercise.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText((getBaseContext()), (parent.getItemIdAtPosition(position) + 2) + " selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });


    calendar = (CalendarView)findViewById(R.id.calendarView);
    reps = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            double repetitions = Double.parseDouble(reps.getText().toString());//Get number of repetitions on that day

            String exerciseName = exercise.getSelectedItem().toString();//Get specific exercise user did

            String calendarDate = calendar.getDate()+"";
        }
    });



    back = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Back);
    back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           finish();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_edit_progress, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

And here is my .XML file:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="EDIT PROGRESS"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:height="50dp"
    android:textSize="22dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="BACK"
    android:id="@+id/Back"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:height="50dp"
    android:textSize="22dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_gradient" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Submit"
    android:id="@+id/Submit"
    android:layout_above="@+id/Back"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="38dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:height="50dp"
    android:textSize="22dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_gradient" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Exercise"
    android:id="@+id/Exercise"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:textSize="20dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Date"
    android:id="@+id/date"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textSize="20dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Repetitions"
    android:id="@+id/repetitions"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/date"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:textSize="20dp" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_below="@+id/repetitions"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/repetitions"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/repetitions"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/repetitions"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/repetitions" />

<Spinner
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Exercise"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/date"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/date"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/Exercise"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/Exercise" />

<CalendarView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/calendarView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/date"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your minimum SDK used for the project is lower than API 11. That's why it's giving you that error.

You can change it in your project settings. Just increase it to API 11 and everything should work fine.

Comment: Ah, thank you! That solves the error. Although it still runs extremely slowly with the calendarView widget. Any ideas for that?

Comment: What triggers the lag, in particular? When does the lag actually start?